# How can I assign Unicode characters to my Chess pieces?

Tags: java, unicode, chess

```java
package Data;
    
import java.util.ArrayList;
    
public class Figurenset {
    boolean color;
    boolean active;
    int id;

    public Figurenset() {
    }
    
    public ArrayList<Figur> initialiseFigures(boolean color, boolean active ) {
        ArrayList<Figur> figures = new ArrayList<Figur>();
        
        //prüft ob Figuren Schwarz sind
        if(color == true) {
            for(int p = 100; p <= 108; p++) {
                figures.add(new Pawn(id = p, color, active));
            }
            for(int r = 110; r <= 111; r++) {
                figures.add(new Rook(id = r, color, active));   
            }
            for(int k = 120; k<=121; k++) {
                figures.add(new Knight(id = k, color, active)); 
            }
            for(int b = 130; b<=131; b++) {
                figures.add(new Bishop(id = b, color, active));
            }
            figures.add(new King(id=140, color, active));
            figures.add(new Queen(id=150, color, active));
        
            for (Figur figur : figures) {
                System.out.println("id: "+figur.id+", color: schwarz"+", active: "+figur.active);
            }
        } else if(color == false){
            for(int p = 200; p <= 208; p++) {
                figures.add(new Pawn(id = p, color, active));
            }
            for(int r = 210; r <= 211; r++) {enter code here
                figures.add(new Rook(id = r, color, active));   
            }
            for(int k = 220; k<=221; k++) {
                figures.add(new Knight(id = k, color, active)); 
            }
            for(int b = 230; b<=231; b++) {
                figures.add(new Bishop(id = b, color, active));
            }
            figures.add(new King(id=240, color, active));
            figures.add(new Queen(id=250, color, active));
            for (Figur figur : figures) {
                System.out.println("id: "+figur.id+", color: weiss"+", active: "+figur.active);
            }
        }

        return figures;
    }
}
```

```java
package Data;
    
public class Figur {
    boolean color;
    boolean active;
    int id;
    boolean legal = false;

    public Figur(int id, boolean color, boolean active) {
        this.color = color;
        this.active = active;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public boolean LegalMoves(int fromX, int toX, int fromY, int toY, boolean legal) {
        if (toX == fromX && toY == fromY)
            return false; // Keine Bewegung
        if (toX < 0 || toX > 7 || fromX < 0 || fromX > 7 || toY < 0 || toY > 7 || fromY < 0 || fromY > 7)
            return false; // Bewegung ausserhalb Brett
        return true;
    }
}
```

The following are the Unicode characters I am trying to implement. I am a total Java noob, and this may be simple, but I read multiple answers and tried various codes and ways to implement but failed miserably.

```java
"\u2654","\u2655","\u2656","\u2657","\u2658","\u2659",
"\u265A","\u265B","\u265C","\u265D","\u265E","\u265F"
```

Comment: "*tried various codes and ways to implement but failed*" - Where are you trying to use the Unicode characters exactly?  I see no such attempts in this code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood the question, but if you want to use special unicode characters you have to "use them" as char.
I havent done anything like you in a while so I might be remembering wrong, but I do believe this is the answer:

```
int a = 2654;
String b = Character.toString((char)a);
```